# I'm struggling on getting the limits right for this cartesian to polar double integral

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I've been working on this homework problem for a while now and I'm just not getting it right.  I'd like for some extra eyes to look at this and hint to me where I'm going wrong.  The cartesian for is:

$$
\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} \int_{\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{y} dxdy
$$

Now, the lower limit of the first integral seems to imply that $x$ is moving on the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, i.e. a circle of radius 2.  Then, the movements of $x$ have a projection onto the $y$ axis of $\sqrt{2} \leq y \leq 2$.  However, as I try to put this on paper.  I come up with all sorts of problems.

The limits placed on $x$ seem to indicate that $x$ follows a path more like the simple function $y=x$ since it's upper limit is simply the value of $y$.  This also seems to make sense because, if I take the function $f(y)=\sqrt{4-y^2}$ then $f(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2}$.  Thus, it would seem that this is a valid relation:

$$
\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} \int_{\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{y} dxdy = \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{y} dxdy
$$

Is this true?

I have tried working this problem from the standpoint that $x$ moves along the path $x=y$, but this makes no sense when trying to determine my limits for $\theta$.  The reason is, the line $y=x$ is at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $r$ moving until it reaches a point of $y=2$ in cartesian basically leaves me with the ordered pair $(\sqrt{2},2)$.  This seems to leave me with a integral of value 0.  This cannot be.

So, what am I getting wrong?  I come out with similar nonsense trying to use $x$ moving along the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ too.

Andy

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ moving "along" a path or a circle? The limits on the given integral are telling you that a fixed value of $y$ between $\sqrt 2$ and $2$, $x$ increases from the circle $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}$ to the line $x=y$, so the circle gives the _leftmost_ boundary of the region of integration and the line the _rightmost_ boundary, as indicated by the image linked to in Chappers' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282-y%5E2%29%3Cx%3Cy) is your region of integration: the important thing is that
$$ \sqrt{1-y^2}<x<y, $$
which is not true for your second integral, which is over a whole rectangle. (Using inequalities like this is one of the easier ways of understanding multiple integral regions: rearranging them tells you how to reparametrise much more easily.)

(Really, you don't want to use polar coordinates for this one: the top line $y=2$ is harder to parametrise)

Comment: There's nothing difficult with converting to polar coordinates, you simply end up having to integrate $\csc^2\theta$.

Comment: It's a matter of taste if you prefer that or the $\sqrt{1-y^2}$, I agree. Of course, the simplest way is to write down the known areas of a triangle and circle sector and subtract, if you want to be picky...

Comment: I don't mind integrating either way.  However the instructions are to convert to polar and integrate.

Comment: I just looked at your plot of the region.  I'm at least happy to say that one of the many times I tried to get the region defined, I did get this region.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wanted to add thanks for helping me through this.  These answers, and comments, helped me to see that I was seriously over complicating things.  AT least, I wasn't thinking of the lower limit of $x$ correctly from the original problem.  I was trying to give it the wrong place in the lower bounds, or trying to make it do something that it wasn't doing.